# Created google spreadsheet with Python3 using the API does not open (permissions)

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have managed to open and edit an existing google sheet using the Google API but I fail when I try to create a new one:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

from pprint import pprint

from googleapiclient import discovery

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

spreadsheet_body = {
    #
}

request = service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet_body)
response = request.execute()

pprint(response)
```

The above creates a file but when I visit the link given in the terminal, I need to grant access! The output of the terminal is below:

```
{'properties': {'autoRecalc': 'ON_CHANGE',
                'defaultFormat': {'backgroundColor': {'blue': 1,
                                                      'green': 1,
                                                      'red': 1},
                                  'padding': {'bottom': 2,
                                              'left': 3,
                                              'right': 3,
                                              'top': 2},
                                  'textFormat': {'bold': False,
                                                 'fontFamily': 'arial,sans,sans-serif',
                                                 'fontSize': 10,
                                                 'foregroundColor': {},
                                                 'italic': False,
                                                 'strikethrough': False,
                                                 'underline': False},
                                  'verticalAlignment': 'BOTTOM',
                                  'wrapStrategy': 'OVERFLOW_CELL'},
                'locale': 'en_US',
                'timeZone': 'Etc/GMT',
                'title': 'Untitled spreadsheet'},
 'sheets': [{'properties': {'gridProperties': {'columnCount': 26,
                                               'rowCount': 1000},
                            'index': 0,
                            'sheetId': 0,
                            'sheetType': 'GRID',
                            'title': 'Sheet1'}}],
 'spreadsheetId': '1bSzXveNHTFDuk6Idj5snsZQVp0RAR-ksb5s_CZusQus',
 'spreadsheetUrl': 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bSzXveNHTFDuk6Idj5snsZQVp0RAR-ksb5s_CZusQus/edit'}
```

Is there a way to parse the spreadsheetId or even better.. its folder (destination) and grant access to a specific user (by email)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [Method: spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) to create a spreadsheet.

There is an available python code that you can use.

```
"""
BEFORE RUNNING:
---------------
1. If not already done, enable the Google Sheets API
   and check the quota for your project at
   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets
2. Install the Python client library for Google APIs by running
   `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`
"""
from pprint import pprint

from googleapiclient import discovery

# TODO: Change placeholder below to generate authentication credentials. See
# https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample
#
# Authorize using one of the following scopes:
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
credentials = None

service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

spreadsheet_body = {
    # TODO: Add desired entries to the request body.
}

request = service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet_body)
response = request.execute()

# TODO: Change
```

code below to process the `response` dict:
pprint(response)

For authorization, you can use the use one of the following OAuth scopes:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

For further information about authorization, you can visit this [Auth Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)

Comment: I think it is related to this line: credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope). It creates the sheet but then it says I have no access granted! :(

Comment: I have added lines in my script that change the permissions of the file. Firstly, I change the permissions of the email address given in the JSON (credentials) and then I do the same for my "real" email.